# Python Pandas - KeyError: "None of Index... are in the columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Trying to red a simple csv file and then trying to visualize one of the variables. But it shows me the key error.

```
import csv
import pandas
from sklearn import linear_model

df = pandas.read_csv("C:\\Users\\kinga\\Desktop\\Testing\\FF.csv")

X = df[['D', 'S']]
y = df['HPC']

regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit(X, y)

predictedHumains = regr.predict([[24, 6]])

print(predictedHumains)

print(regr.coef_)
```

ERROR CODES

```
File "c:\Users\kinga\Desktop\Testing\feux de foret.py", line 7, in <module>
    X = df[['D', 'S']]
  File "C:\Users\kinga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3511, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns._get_indexer_strict(key, "columns")[1]
  File "C:\Users\kinga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 5782, in _get_indexer_strict
    self._raise_if_missing(keyarr, indexer, axis_name)
  File "C:\Users\kinga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 5842, in _raise_if_missing
    raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")KeyError: "None of [Index(['D', 'S'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
PS C:\Users\kinga>
```

Comment: Does the csv file contain columns named `D` and `S`?

Comment: Yes, Of course 
HPC  ;D;S
6;3.25;0.07
6;5;0.01
21;27.1667;5
6;5.916;0.03
37;77.5;35.35
10;14.833;9
36;43.083;8
7;10.25;4
9;3;2
9;6;0.2
38;82;15
7;10.25;1
8;8;0.05
7;6;0.5
9;4.25;1.05
5;4;1.05
7;7.33;1
20;3.33;1.6
4;12;1
7;6.75;1.5
5;1.167;0.015
12;12.667;0.75
26;68.25;15
18;2.15;0.15

Comment: Should the csv file name has the .csv or not?

Comment: By default, csv files are assumed to use commas as column separators.  But that file uses semicolons, not commas. So it probably thinks you have one giant column named `HPC ;D;S`.  You have to tell `read_csv()` to use a semicolon as the column separator.

Comment: So, what type of extension do you suggest to save it after the editing on Excel?

Comment: csv is still the correct extension.  You need to pass an extra argument `sep=';'` to the read function.

Answer (score 0):

Your csv file uses ';' as separator for column values.
So, you need to pass sep=';' in the pandas read function. as suggested by @John Gordon.
Try this noe

```
df = pandas.read_csv("C:\\Users\\kinga\\Desktop\\Testing\\FF.csv", sep=';')
```